# Double-clicking a cell in a sheet to generate filtered data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a workbook that will provide an overview of select products in manufacturing.

I am trying to allow for double clicking within a table range to filter data in a different sheet.

To illustrate, the range of the table I would like to apply this code to is B2 to Y40.
Upon double clicking cell B2 I would like to apply two separate filters based on the data in B1 and A2 in the other sheet.
Upon double clicking cell D38, I would like it to apply two separate filters based on D1 and A38.

I found this code in a somewhat similar question posed on this website.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Update Table14 to your table name
    'Update Field to column number of the field you are filtering
    'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table
    'Change on to the column number where your click should cause this action
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
    Sheet7.ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
    'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table
    Sheet7.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to change the ActiveCell.Column to a table range, and change the criteria to achieve the desired filter results mentioned above?

Comment: Your question is not so clear, at least for me. So, do you have a table (named "Table14") in `Sheet7`? Then, you said that your code should work on the range "B2:Y40" and you also stated something about two filters...  `ActiveCell` from there should be the `Target` cell in your code, but where to use the second value you were mentioning about? Forgetting about the code, can you better explain (in words) what you want accomplishing?

Comment: I will do my best to explain better in words what it is that I am trying to accomplish. I have a table range B2:Y40 in which I would like to make it possible to double click any value and to filter a separate sheet. Based on the column and row that the value is in I would like to filter this separate sheet. The filters should not come from the active cell that was double clicked but based on the cell that was pressed the filters should come from the A column with the same row number, and the same column (as was pressed) but the first row. These would be 2 separate filters based on those cells.

Comment: Firstly, do you know what a Table does mean? Do you have such a table in the active sheet, or you name a range of cells as table? Than, you mean that needing two filter criteria? The cells you mentioned in the question? And are you sure that you need to filter (using two criteria) based on the first table column?

Comment: I asked the last question because the comment `'Update Table14 to your table name` suggests that this was the case of the one making the code and it looks improbable to have the exact sheet and Table name...

Comment: Which column(s) in the worksheet to be filtered will you apply the two filters to? Does the mentioned worksheet also contain a table? Do clarify. I understand the 'criteria part' (e.g. if `Y12` then `Y1` and `A12`).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes the mentioned worksheet also contains a table. There are 2 columns that the filters would be applied to these are column F and K. The criteria Y1 would be applied to column K and the criteria A12 would be applied to column F.

Comment: @FaneDuru The table is a cell range that was named Table 1 (in the active worksheet). I know that the table name still needs to be changed to the table name that I have set for that range of cells in the code. I would be able to change that accordingly. The only things I don't know is how to increase the range of the double click code to include the whole table rather then a column and set the 2 different filter criteria and apply these to the respective columns in the table on a different sheet.

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes I fully understand! I just looked at it, awnsered the comments first, the code looks to be good as far as I can understand it. No the sheet and table are not named that but I am capable of interchanging that with the actual names :). The only thing is that I don't need to filter using both criteria, they should filter separate columns as mentioned in my comment to VBasic2008. Thanks for helping!

Comment: So, do you really have a `Sheet7` and a `Table14` on it... I will adapt the code to filter on two columns...

Comment: No, I do not have these names for my sheet and table, is it not possible for me to interchange those names with the names of the relevant tables and sheet (as mentioned in the code)?

Comment: What does "is it not possible for me to interchange those names with the names of the relevant tables and sheet" should mean? I thought that the comments have been done by the one creating the code. Should I understand that you put them? If yes, how to understand the fact that you need this code and you do  not know on which sheet and on which table (if a table involved...) to make the filtering? Can you explain it? Is it something I am missing?

Comment: The person who wrote the code, wrote the comments. I'm not really sure as to what it is that is unclear. The comments explain how I should change the code to fit to my sheet & table. So as written in the comments that is what I will do to make it work on my file. I hope this makes sense. Am I correct to understand that you think that I am not working with a table? I have an existing sheet that has a large table (if it can be defined as an object table I'm not sure, from your comment I gather that it probably isn't?). If not can I adjust Sheet7.ListObjects("Table14") to Sheet7.Range("A1:Z99")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Filter in Another Worksheet

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick( _
        ByVal Target As Range, _
        Cancel As Boolean)

    Const dName As String = "Sheet2" ' adjust destination tab name
    Const dField1 As Long = 6 ' 6 is "F"
    Const dField2 As Long = 11 ' 11 is "K"

    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = srg _
        .Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1, srg.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)

    If Intersect(Target, irg) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim dCrit1 As String: dCrit1 = CStr(Cells(1, Target.Column).Value)
    Dim dCrit2 As String: dCrit2 = CStr(Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value)

    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Worksheets(dName)
    If dws.AutoFilterMode Then
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    drg.AutoFilter Field:=dField1, Criteria1:=dCrit1
    drg.AutoFilter Field:=dField2, Criteria1:=dCrit2
    
    'Cancel = True
    dws.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for writing a solution to my problem. It seems your solution is more robust to changes then the previous one. Which is why I have tried using it in my file. Somehow I cannot get the double click function to work at all, is there something I am missing? I have put the code in VBA under the main Worksheet, and changed Sheet 2 to the sheet that should be filtered. Upon double clicking any of the cells in the main worksheet it simply opens up the formula as normal instead of performing the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next updated code (according to what you said). But I still have some doubts that you need to filter Table24 in Sheet7... Please, clarify this aspect.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:Y40")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim Crit1 As String, Crit2 As String
        Crit1 = cells(1, Target.Column).value
        Crit2 = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
        'Update "Table14", using your real table name. Or a range, if no table is involved...
        'The filter field must also be updated according to your need (now it is 1 - first table column)
        Sheet7.ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Crit1
        Sheet7.ListObjects("Table14").Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Crit2
        'Update Sheet7 to reference the sheet containing your table!
        Cancel = True  'otherwise, you cannot activate another sheet if the double clicked cell will be in edit mode
        Sheet7.Activate
   End If
End Sub
```

The above code should be copied in the sheet code module, where you try double clicking.

Comment: I don't think you can double-click two cells. Also, `Crit2 = Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value`. Otherwise, that's about it except it is unclear (in the question) which fields will be filtered.

Comment: That is correct. I initially understood that he needs the left cell value to the double clicked one (looking only to the first example). And the `Target.cells.count` was a (bad) reflex when using such events involving Target... I will correct it. Thanks! Anyhow, I have the impression that the above code will not serve to the OP. He does not look to understand what a Table means and how to adapt the code for his need. I would like to be  wrong...